# Render form using partials instead of helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an app where it would be advantageous to render form fields (such as `email_field`s) using partials rather than the existing builder methods.  As an example, it would be helpful to have something like:

```
<%= rendered_form_for @article do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %> # renders /forms/text_field
  <%= f.email_field :author %> # renders /forms/email_field
  <%= f.submit "Create" %> # renders /forms/submit
<% end %>
```

I've tried creating a form builder per [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#customizing-form-builders):

```
# Used with rendered_form_for (a helper that injects this builder)
class RenderedFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def email_field(attribute, options={})
    options.merge! attr: attribute
    render partial: '/forms/email_field', **options
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, the `render` method doesn't exist in this context, so this throws an error.

Any hints or suggestions on how to render a form using partials, rather than helpers?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `ActionController::Base.helpers.render ...`

Comment: @Iceman A good starting point, and I'll keep digging on it, but that doesn't seem to receive the context from the rest of the app.  For example, it doesn't have any directories to search in.  `ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial forms/_email_field with {:snip]}. Searched in:):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an attribute called `@template` which would offer the `render` method.  The code could be refactored to:

```
# Used with rendered_form_for (a helper that injects this builder)
class RenderedFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def email_field(attribute, options={})
    options.merge! attr: attribute
    @template.render partial: '/forms/email_field', locals: options
  end
end
```

Also edited in the `locals` hash for defining local values within the rendered partial.